# og:image meta tag in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I have some dynamic images defined as follows on my page:

```
<%= image_tag(@recipe.image.url(:fixed), :class => 'recipe_image_show') %>
```

I am looking for a way to define og:image with this code. The og:description code seen below works perfectly:

```
<meta property="og:description" content= "<%= @recipe.description %>" />
```

But if I use the code below then it doesn't want to work:

```
<meta property="og:image" content='<%= image_tag(@recipe.image.url(:fixed), :class => 'recipe_image_show') %>'/>
```

Any suggestions? I realised I have used single quotes here but using double quotes for some reason results the page to disregard the '/>' part of the meta tag and display it as text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the chat discussion, OP is **hosting** the images on **S3**.

So, define the `meta` tag as below:

```
<meta property="og:image" content='<%= @recipe.image.url(:fixed) %>'/>
```

This will be evaluated to:

```
<meta property="og:image" content='https://s3....amazonaws.com/path/to/image.jpg'/>
```

**NOTE:**

If image was stored on the your own application server then you could use it as:

```
<meta property="og:image" content='<%= image_url @recipe.image.url(:fixed) %>'/>
```

Comment: I have the image in `app/assets/images/my_image.png` and am using `image_url('my_image.png')`, but I see: `Provided og:image URL, https://www.example.com/images/my_image.png could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type. Any ideas what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

if you are on rails 6 with wepback this one worked for me

```rb
- meta 'og:image': "#{asset_pack_url "static/image.webp"}"
```

check [asset_pack_url on github](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/5780a0a9b969560596e3a0ace2398c7e291f9c0b/lib/webpacker/helper.rb#L37) for reference

your image path may vary, lookup `manifest.json` for this manner

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Click "Scrape Again" to reload Facebook Cache

Use full path with image_url("example.png")